# Fetch data from firebase in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a real-time firebase database with a structure like this:

```
-- places
   -- user1 uid
      -- name:
      -- latitude: 
      -- longitude:
   -- user2 uid
      -- name:
      -- latitude: 
      -- longitude:
```

When fetching the data from firebase, I wanted to store it like this

```
-- user1 name
   -- latitude
   -- longitude
-- user2 name
   -- latitude
   -- longitude
```

Currently I have this code structure which loops through the data, but I am stuck on getting each data and store it as shown above.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      places: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('places/');
    ref.once('value', (snapshot) => { 
      snapshot.forEach(snapshotchild => {
        snapshotchild.forEach(data => {

        })
      })

    });
  }
```

Comment: so your uid ( id) will be name?

Comment: I didnt use firebase in react-native, but i think it returns a promise.

Comment: Can you show what you are getting in data? Do a `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data table, I am assuming you are getting the data somewhat like this

```
const places = {
 user1Uid: {
  name: 'av',
  latitude: '1000',
  longitude: '1000'
 },
user2Uid: {
  name: 'we',
  latitude: '1000',
  longitude: '1000'
 }
}
```

If this is how it it is, you can manipulate the data using `Array.forEach`, `for in` or even with `Array.reduce`,
For example to

```
const obj = {};
Object.keys(places).forEach(item => {
  obj[places[item].name] = {
     latitude: places[item].latitude,
     longitude: places[item].longitude
   }

});
console.log(obj);
```

or if you wanna use reduce,

```
const newObj = Object.keys(places).reduce((accumulator, item) => Object.assign({
    [places[item].name]: {
     latitude: places[item].latitude,
     longitude: places[item].longitude
   }

 }, accumulator), {});
console.log(newObj);
```

You will get an object in console like

```
{
  "we": {
    "latitude": "1000",
    "longitude": "1000"
  },
  "av": {
    "latitude": "1000",
    "longitude": "1000"
  }
}
```

If you wanna learn more about Reduce here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Happy coding :)